# Uniform Scattering with vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient, brush

I'm attempting to create a random spread of dots to create a gradient look. I'm getting really close to the effect I want by blending two scatter brushes. The issue I'm having is that the blended brushes creates unwanted lines, and the dots run into each other. I keep adjusting the settings with no luck.

Here's the effect I'm wanting to achieved.

- Smooth transition
- On Circular path
- Dots don't converge
- Scattered at random-ish

[image: Gradual Scattered effect]

Here's how close I'm able to get:

- Blended scatters create unwanted lines
- Dots converge
- Spacing isn't gradual from edge to center

[image: What I'm able to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astute Graphics has an Illustrator extension "Stipplism" . It obviously can convert greyshades to dot densities + more. I haven't it, but check it here https://astutegraphics.com/software/stipplism/

A radial gradient can be the first objects to get it.

**If you do not want Stipplism** and the blending approach isn't good, then you can trace a bitmap, which has the effect.

The bitmap is easily copyable from GIMP. There you make a radial gradient and dither it to 1 bit indexed mode.

At first make an empty image, have quite low pixel dimensions to keep Illustrator load reasonable. Here is a 200 x 200 pixels RGB image and a radial gradient is just under construction:

[image]

There's a circular selection to keep the edges empty. The gradient isn't fully linear. There's a middle stop to make the sparse center wider. The shade range is only about 60%...100% white, because darker greys will make contiguous blocks in the dithering process.

Image mode is converted from RGB to Indexed (it's in the Image menu). Here's the dialog

[image]

I converted it back to RGB, but it seems to work in Illustrator as well when it's copied and pasted as is. Here's the tracing dialog:

[image]

Note: the accuracy is stretched to maximum in the tracing settings and white is ignored.

The result contains nearly square dots. If you want round ones, do the following:

- expand the live trace to make the result editable
- with Path > Simplify transform all curves to straight lines
- apply filter Stylize > Round corners; you must measure one dot in high zoom to see the proper radius if you want to be careful. Fortunately too big radius doesn't harm.
- make the result editable with Object > Expand Appearance

Here's a zoomed picture of the final result:

[image]

Comment: Yes! That Stipplism extension is exactly what it needed. Thank you! And so much easier too. It created the result exactly as I had hoped. Nice and clean with the quality slider.

Answer (score 3):

Make the blend from a big circle to a small circle in the center

[image: Blend]

Draw a *dot* and create a **Scatter Brush** with this settings and apply it to the outer circle

[image: Outer Brush]

Duplicate the *OUTER BRUSH*, change the scatter settings and apply it to the inner circle

[image: Inner]

Copy/Paste in front the blend and apply the brushes to the outer and inner circle again

[image: Result]

This final result is made with three overlapping blends:

[image: blends]

Comment: but then the dots would still overlap no?

Comment: Yes, I make my own interpretation ;-) that's why I clarified it at the end of the answer. To don't overlap dots the solution is using just only one blend, but adjusting the OUTER BRUSH scatter options.