# How to achieve this pixel-y vibes effect

Tags: photoshop-effects, pixel

What's the best way to achieve an effect like this design?

[image]

Comment: This can be considered as a not so good version of the stipple effect. I have offered it few days ago as a replacement for the real thing. Of course the questioner selected a high quality version. You can like it, too (I do not sell them). He used it only for a radial gradient. See the discussion https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114604/uniform-scattering-with-vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Image > Mode > Greyscale*

then *Image > Mode > Bitmap*

Set the use method to "Diffusion Dither".

[image]

You can change back to RGB mode once it has been done, then add other elements such as text.